# Conditional resource in serverless

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, serverless

I would like to add an AWS resource conditionally based on presence of an env var. I tried `serverless-cloudformation-parameter-setter` but I get a generic error on deployment and I don't see what I need to do to fix it

I'm trying to deploy a simple lambda + SQS stack and if a env var is defined also subscribe the queue to the topic denoted by the env var - or if the var is not defined then not do that part at all, just the lambda and the queue

This is what I tried:

```
plugins:
- serverless-cloudformation-parameter-setter

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-1

functions:
  update:
    handler: index.update
    events:
    - sqs:
        arn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - Queue
          - Arn

custom:
  cf-parameters:
    SourceTopicArn: "${env:UPDATE_SNS_ARN}"

resources:
  Parameters:
    SourceTopicArn:
      Type: string
  Resources:
    Queue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    Subscription:
      Type: "AWS::SNS::Subscription"
      Condition: SourceTopicArn
      Properties:
        TopicArn:
          Ref: SourceTopicArn
        Endpoint:
          Ref: Queue
```

The error I receive is: `The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unrecognized parameter type: string`

If I remove all the parameter stuff it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Type` has to be `String`, not `string`. See the [supported parameter data types section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-properties-type) in the docs.